# Alternativa para MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom, atualmente uso o software MySQL Workbench para fazer meus scripts, queria um programa mais leve, alguém conhece/poderia me passar algumas alternativas?

Não quero PHPMYADMIN

Obs: desenvolvo com PHP - não sei se isso influencia muito.

Comment: heidisql , utilizo para desenvolver com php também, é bem leve e muito util<br/>
Segue o link: https://www.heidisql.com/download.php

Comment: https://www.heidisql.com/; https://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-mysql; https://www.dbvis.com/download/

Comment: Antes de colocar essa pergunta estava dando uma olhada neste, será que este é o melhor por aí ? @MurilloGoulart

Comment: Eu já usei a versão free do dbvis.com/download, é bem leve, porém não tem alguns recursos mais avançados.

Comment: Já usou este: http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/ ? @MurilloGoulart

Comment: Não, parece bem completo também. Porém, geralmente quanto mais completo, mais pesado, o que você não quer.

Comment: @MuriloGoulart Verdade, obrigado!

Comment: sqldbx, este se conecta nos principais bancos além de ser portable.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo em meu serviço o **SQLYog**, ele é pago e você pode tentar uma versão TRIAL por aqui: https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog

Já utilizei também o **NAVICAT**, acho que o Yog tem mais opções interessantes, mas o Navicat trabalha melhor com algumas seleções de tabelas. Também é pago, trial aqui: https://www.navicat.com/pt/download

Se você procura um software livre, um que eu já usei e recomendo é o **ToadSQL** (*ToadWorld*), utilizo bastante ele por causa da opção de realizar consultas em múltiplos bancos (opção interessantíssima para quem possui vários bancos para clientes distintos). Você pode baixar procurando por "ToadSQL", existem algumas opções e também documentações, então sugiro que dê uma navegada no site deles.

Comment: Lembrando que o SQLYog tem uma versão gratuita communit https://github.com/webyog/sqlyog-community/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 1):

Se você utiliza MacOS, sem dúvidas o [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com).

1. É nativo para MacOS
2. Feito exclusivamente para o MySQL
3. Se você mexe com permissões, tem uma excelente UI para tal
4. É código aberto e gratuito

Se você não usa MacOS ou está acostumado às IDEs da JetBrains, vá com o [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/). Ele é bem caro, mas é muito completo. Se for pra uso educacional, só mandar um *request* que você ganha todo o pacote da JetBrains por 1 ano (no meu caso).

1. Te dá a possibilidade de trabalhar com múltiplos DBMSs
2. Se você gosta, ele tem um ótimo auto-complete
3. Te dá insights para otimização de queries
4. Um pró para alguns e contra para outros: é da JetBrains

Comment: Vlw, um que eu gostei de usar é o HeidiSQL, bem levinho ele. Uso windows 10 e Debian 9 (atualmente)